# How to prevent inserting same value in two columns in one Table?

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I'm trying to solve problem which will compare ***BEFORE INSERTING*** columns values `partnerCode` and `partnerCodeOwner1` with `username` in the table below, If `partnerCode and partnerCodeOwner1` values same with `username` should **error** message And insert shouldn't be completed!
My attempt below but incorrect!

Is it possible to implement such condition?

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*******', '********', '***********');


      $user_check_query = "SELECT partnerCodeOwner1 FROM refer where  randomfield='$partnerCode'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);



// --------------------HERE I'm trying to check for the same value in columns--------
//But incorrect! Syntax error?

    if ($row) { // compare columns But incorrect
    if ($row['username'] === ['partnerCodeOwner1']) {
      array_push($errors, "U can't invest to yourself");
    }




    if(empty($row['partnerCodeOwner1'])) {
        $query = "update refer 
                    set partnerCodeOwner1= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'  
                where randomfield='$partnerCode' ;";
    }else {
        $query = "update refer 
                    set partnerCode= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'  
                where randomfield='$partnerCode'  ";        
    }

    mysqli_query($db, $query);
}       
?>
```

**Example**

**table:** `refer`

```
  ID      randomfield    username      partnerCode    partnerCodeOwner1  
+-------+ ------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|   1   | A45scdv     |  John       |  Not same       |    John   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
|   2   | das654d     | Alex        |  Alex           | Not same  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: It would also help to give an idea of what you are trying to do with those columns as someone might be able to suggest other solutions to your porblem

Comment: As suggested by @ypercubeᵀᴹ latest version of `mysql` has `CHECK` option implemented. You can add the `CHECK (partnerCodeOwner1 <> partnerCode)` to the `partnerCodeOwner1` column definition. That prevents INSERT/UPDATE violating the condition.

Comment: @JoeW In my case, As you can see there column `randomfield` belongs to `username`, And who enters `randomfield` of someone's code , it will be inserted to owner of `randomfield` in `partnercode or partnercodeOwner1`. I'm trying to do Owner of `randomfield` should not enter/insert their own `randomfield` code! You got me Dude?

Comment: @Kondybas Thanks for your reply! Can you write properly code that you recommended? Cause I bit didn't understand the syntax.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Almost latest version! Is it possible to do such implementation? Cause I couldn't solve for a week :((((

Comment: Perhaps a `TRIGGER` could check and complain.

Comment: @RickJames But we should notify the user in case they entered their own code